# Lucene: query or filter for relational search for "owned" documents?

Tags: search, filter, lucene, relational

I have a data set whereby documents can optionally be associated to a user id. Say that the documents represent books, and each book can have one or more owner. When searching, I want to match on books that I own first before matching on books I don't own.  Then, I want all results owned by me to be sorted at the top of the results before results that are not owned by me.  So the data might look like:

```
Owner ID             Book Title
--------             ----------
13                   To Have and To Have Not
14                   To Have and To Have Not
19                   To Have and To Have Not
15                   Snow Crash
17                   Snow Crash
18                   Cryptonomicon
14                   Of Mice And Men
```

Say that my user id is 14 and I search on "have", I want to find the book owned by me first rather than the one owned by 13 or 19 (so that I know to sort it at the top of the list because I own it).  But if I search on "crash", I want to find either of the books matching that title even though I don't own either.  Because I don't own them, they'd show up lower in the sort.  So if I did a fuzzy search on "a", I would see all matching books owned by me at the top of the list, and the rest after.

I am a little stuck on whether this is a query, a filter, or both.  For example, I could write a filter that eliminates all duplicate titles, giving preference to those owned by me, and then just perform a simple search on the remainder (assuming that filters are applied before searches). Then, a custom sort based on owner would be straightforward.

But I am not sure how to implement the filter.  It is not a simple DuplicateFilter because it operates on two fields.  It is similar to the security filter example in section 5.6.7 of Lucene in Action, except that I still want to be able to see documents that I don't own, if I don't own a book with the same title.  The custom filter in section 6.4 is also close, but my problem is more complex because it depends on two fields.

While iterating over the documents, the filter would have to remember which titles have been seen, and then keep the ones that I own.  For example if it iterated over the values above in order, it would see the title "To Have and To Have Not", not owned by me; and then see the same title again, owned by me, and have to know that it should drop the first doc and keep the second.  I can't think of how to do this without using a lot of memory, essentially keeping all titles in memory while iterating, which seems very expensive. It isn't a simple "match" function because whether or not I match depends on the other documents in the set.

Thanks much for any guidance or info.

Comment: Have you tried to simply put large query-time boost on owner field (you have multi-value field owner, not separate book for each owner, right?).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a custom sort on the query hits, where if 2 documents have identical scores then the document with a 'priority owner' would be listed first in the search results.